# how to Create a login page in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

hey can someone please help i just want to create a login page in MVC 4.
here is my login code,i want to access index page after clicking on login button. the below code is not working properly whenever m clicking on login nothing is happening.
Can someone please help me out, just new to MVC

Controller code

```
  using MvcApplication1.Models;
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.Mvc;
 using System.Web.Security;

 namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
 {
 public class LoginController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Login/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult UserLogin(Customer  d)
    {
        using (CustomerDataEntities oe = new CustomerDataEntities())
        {
            var user = oe.Customers.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(d.UserName) && a.Password.Equals(d.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
            return new JsonResult { Data = user, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }

    }

}
```

}

Login View

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
 }

     <h2>Login</h2>
       @model MvcApplication1.Models.Customer
         @{
           Layout = null;
           }

       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
               <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
            <title>Login</title>


     </head>
      <body>


      <h2>Sign In</h2>
       <div>
      @using (@Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login"))
       {
          <table>
            <tr>
                <td>

                    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.UserName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.UserName)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.Password)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.Password)
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

    }


    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Register", "AddEditRecord", "Home") if u dont have userid please click here
    </p>

</div>
```

Comment: If you want to redirect then why are you returning Json? - use `return RedirectToAction{"Index");` But I strongly recommend you go to the MVC site and work through some tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 [httppost]
 public ActionResult Login(Customer  d)
{
    using (CustomerDataEntities oe = new CustomerDataEntities())
    {
        var user = oe.Customers.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(d.UserName) && a.Password.Equals(d.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
        return redirectoAction("Index");
    }

}
```

Comment: whats the problem in this?

Comment: thats an answer to question above

Comment: thanks for sharing this info... i know this is an answer. I am asking the OP and downvoter that why did he downvote it??

Comment: thats true..people usually downvote without leaving a reason

Comment: this is working thank you so much for you rply.you made my day

Comment: one more thing can you tell me the coding how to show that customer not exist

Comment: if this solves ur problem, then u should mark it as an answer

Comment: if(user!=null) {return redirectoaction("index");}. Try it on your own.. It will help in gaining more understanding as a beginner

Answer (score 0):

```
  public ActionResult UserLogin(Customer d) {
    var user = 0;
    using(CustomerDataEntities oe = new CustomerDataEntities()) {
        user = oe.Customers.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(d.UserName) && a.Password.Equals(d.Password)).count();

    }
    if (user != 0) {
        return RedirectToAction("Index")
    } else {
        //RedirectToActionto some other page
    }

   }
```

Comment: hey thanks for your rply can you help me, just wanna see messege there if m puting worng username and password like customer not found